# iPad SplitView as subview

Tags: xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm dealing with an iPad project that manages a custom menu and a subview with different stuff on in it, now i want to try to put on this subview a splitview. Is it possible? How can I do it? How can I build my splitview without any template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple human interface guidelines forbid this and say that the UISplitViewController must be installed as the Root View Controller so it would be best to redesign your app with this in mind since they will not approve it when submitted for review otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is an old question it's still worth adding that Apple seem to have relaxed their rules. I have had a couple of apps approved that have a SplitView inside a TabBar.